# Selecting class using strings

Tags: php, string, class, select

I want to write an extension system for my CMS. I want the extensions to be installed by copying a folder into the extensions folder. The content of the extension is a class with the same name as the name of the folder. So my CMS can list the extensions by the names of the folders in the extension folder. The problem is that I can't find a way to select the class even though I have a string containing it's name.

So to sum up, is there any way to create an instance of a class or calling static functions of a class, by referring to said class using a string with the class name?

I hope you understand what I mean and thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like so?

```
$classname = "myClass";

$object = new $classname();
```